# If $a_{n+1}=\frac {a_n^2+5} {a_{n-1}}$ then $a_{n+1}=Sa_n+Ta_{n-1}$ for some $S,T\in \Bbb Z$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations

**Question**

> Let $$a_{n+1}:=\frac {a_n^2+5} {a_{n-1}},\, a_0=2,a_1=3$$
>
> Prove that there exists integers $S,T$ such that  $a_{n+1}=Sa_n+Ta_{n-1}$.

**Attempt**

I calculated the first few values of $a_n$: $a_2=7,a_3=18, a_4=47$ so I'd have the system of diophantine equations:
$$
7=3S+2T\\
18=7S+3T\\
47=18S+7T
$$

Now: it *seems* that all of the $a_i$ are pairwise coprime, so these equations should always have solutions, but how could I check that the intersection of all the solutions is not $\emptyset$?

Comment: Should it read $\dots Ta_{n-1}$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks!

Comment: (3,18) and (2,18) aren't coprime.  What did you mean by $a_i$ are pairwise coprime?

Comment: No great insight, but $S=2,T=-1$ works.  Just by inspection.  There is, presumably, a more systematic way to proceed.

Comment: @rVitale I meant $a_{i-1},a_i,a_{i+1}$, but I failled at seeing that...

Comment: (sorry, meant to type $S=3, T=-1$. )

Comment: I'm confused about the order of quantifiers. Does a single $S$ and $T$ have to work for all $n$, or can we have different $S$ and $T$ for different $n$?

Comment: Closed form is $$a_n=\left( \frac {3+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n+\left(\frac {3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$

Comment: @lulu you got that by solving the linear recurrence right? I'm mostly interested on how to get the $(3,-1)$. I think there has to be another way than guessing

Comment: Yes.  My "method":  stare at it until the linear form becomes clear, ask computer to check $100$ cases.  Then solve the linear system and verify that the quadratic relation holds.  Best I can come up with, sorry!

Comment: @ColmBhandal A single pair $(T,S)$ must work for all n!

Comment: I tried assuming that $a_n=\lambda ^n$ but that fails.  I don't see how to guess the particular closed form, or anything like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the initial data and recursion, compute $a_0=2,a_1=3,a_2=7,a_3=18$.

If we have an $S$ and $T$ so that $a_{n+1}=Sa_n+Ta_{n-1}$, then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\7&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}S\\T\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}7\\18\end{bmatrix}\implies\begin{bmatrix}S\\T\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3&2\\7&3\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}7\\18\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}3\\-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, to verify that the linear recursion $a_{n+1}=3a_n-a_{n-1}$ implies
$$
a_{n+1}a_{n-1}-a_n^2=5\tag{1}
$$
Assume the linear recursion, then
$$
\begin{align}
&\left(a_{n+2}a_n-a_{n+1}^2\right)-\left(a_{n+1}a_{n-1}-a_n^2\right)\\
&=(3a_{n+1}-a_n)a_n-a_{n+1}^2-a_{n+1}a_{n-1}+a_n^2\\
&=3a_{n+1}a_n-a_{n+1}^2-a_{n+1}a_{n-1}\\
&=a_{n+1}(3a_n-a_{n-1})-a_{n+1}^2\\
&=a_{n+1}^2-a_{n+1}^2\\
&=0\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the linear recursion and $(1)$ imply that
$$
a_{n+2}a_n-a_{n+1}^2=5\tag{3}
$$

Comment: Could you clarify on the implication $a_{n+1}=3a_n-a_{n-1} \rightarrow a_{n+1}a_{n-1}-a_n^2=5$? I couldn't understand that part.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: $(2)$ shows that $a_{n+1}=3a_n-a_{n-1}\implies a_{n+2}a_n-a_{n+1}^2=a_{n+1}a_{n-1}-a_n^2$. The fact that $2\cdot7-3^2=5$ starts the induction.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $a_n$ can be expressed as $a_{n+1}=Sa_n+Ta_{n-1}$.

Then $a_n$ is expressed as
$$a_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n$$
Then
$$a_{n+1}a_{n-1}=(A\alpha^{n+1}+B\beta^{n+1})(A\alpha^{n-1}+B\beta^{n-1})$$
$$=A^2\alpha^{2n}+AB\alpha^{n-1}\beta^{n+1}+AB\alpha^{n+1}\beta^{n-1}+B^2\beta^{2n}$$
And
$$a_n^2+5=A^2\alpha^{2n}+2AB\alpha^n\beta^n+B^2\beta^{2n}+5$$
Therefore,
$$AB(\alpha^{n-1}\beta^{n+1}+\alpha^{n+1}\beta^{n-1})=2AB\alpha^n\beta^n+5$$
should hold for all $n$.

This is possible only when $\alpha\beta=1$ and if $\alpha\beta=1$,
$$AB(\alpha^2+\beta^2)=2AB+5$$
$$AB({\alpha-\beta})^2=5\tag{1}$$
Using initial conditions
$$a_0=A+B$$
$$a_1=A\alpha+B\beta$$
Solving linear equations,
$$A=\frac{a_1-a_0\beta}{\alpha-\beta}$$
$$B=\frac{a_0\alpha-a_1}{\alpha-\beta}$$
Applying to (1),
$$(a_0\beta-a_1)(a_0\alpha-a_1)+5=0$$
$$a_0^2-a_0a_1(\alpha+\beta)+a_1^2+5=0$$
$$\therefore \alpha+\beta=\frac{a_0^2+a_1^2+5}{a_0a_1}$$
As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are roots of $x^2-Sx-T$,
$$S=\alpha+\beta=\frac{a_0^2+a_1^2+5}{a_0a_1}$$
$$T=-\alpha\beta=-1$$
(*) In our case, $a_0=2$ and $a_1=3$ gives us $\alpha+\beta=3$ that leads to lulu's solution.

Comment: How does one find closed form for recurrences / recursive sequences? Usually I dislike the "First assume" approaches as this suggest one already knows it will work or knows what the result will be. What do I have to read? What should I read?

Comment: Nice work, but missing the verification step. In other words, you show that *if* $S, T$ exist then they are $3,-1$. But to verify you would need to put the equation back into the recurrence and make sure it checks out. I'm sure it does, so I'm not going to lose sleep over it.

Comment: Well, I started this to prove that such $S$ and $T$ don't exist but I found they do exist. So I ended up with showing that the solution can be found in a closed form for any given initial condition, if they exist. I could have turned into a nice proof for existence but I ran out of my energy. Thanks for your comments anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the base case $n=1$ is easily verifiable. 
Since the sequence is increasing, $a_n >1$ for $n>1.$

Now assume for all natural numbersn $n$ less than or equal to $k$ that:

$a_{n+1} = Pa_n +Qa_{n-1}$  has integer solutions $Q$ and $P$ (inductive hypothesis).

Then note that:

$a_{k+2} =M_1a_{k+1} +N_1a{k}$    $\Leftrightarrow$  $a_{k+2}=M_1(M_2a_k +N_2a_{k-1}) +N_1(M_3a_{k-1} +N_3a_{k-2})$$=...=C_{1}a_1 +C_2a_0=3C_1 +2C_2 $ for some arbitrary integers $C_1$ and $C_2$

But since the Diophantine equation $N=ax+by$ has integer solutions $x$ and $y$ for all $N>ab-a-b$, and since $a_{k+2} >1$, it follows that there exists integer solutions $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: The coefficients $T, K$ has to be the same for all $n$ ... and it seems that $T=-1, K=3$ would do (it works for $n=2, 3, 4$). The question is whether is works for all $n$. Induction sounds like a good idea, btw.

Comment: Why do you say that? The way I understood it was that each term has to be a linear combination of the previous two terms.

Comment: please note that $T$ and $K$ are independent of the index in the question title as well as in the example given in the question.

Comment: @J.Gudal- I found the same thing confusing. This is a classic case where implicity quantifiers lead to ambiguity. We want: $\exists T, S \forall n P(n)$ whereas you have $\forall n \exists T, S P(n)$ which is weaker.

Comment: I understand the problem. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @J.Gudal I do not understand the notation you use in your answer. Particularly the step beginning $a_{k+2}= \dots$. What are $x_0, x_1$? Where did you get the $3$ and $2$ from? The step is very hard to follow, without a lot of effort.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Sorry that should have been $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Comment: @J.Gudal OK, it's starting to make more sense, but you are still skipping a lot of steps in between. You start what looks like a chain of equalities and somehow arrive at $a_1C_1 + a_0C_2$. I do not see the algebra fully worked out here. It is a headache to read.

Comment: @ColmBhandal At each stage we are essentially reducing a linear combination of $a_n$ and $a_{n-1}$ to a linear combination $a_{n-2}$ and $a_{n-3}$ but of course such a sequence of reductions terminates at $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Comment: @J.Gudal Yes fair enough, I see the idea, but I think it could be presented more elegantly. I'm sorry to be pedantic here, but wouldn't it be a lot nicer if the induction hypothesis itself was that all terms $a_{n+1}$ are a linear combination of $a_0, a_1$ rather than $a_n, a_{n-1}$? Anyway, maybe I'm just being pedantic.

Answer (score 2):

The result is $a_{n + 1} = 3 a_n - a_{n - 1}$.

**HINT:** Let $a_{k + 1} = a_k + b_k$. Then, by the original equation, we get $$a_{n - 1} + b_{n - 1} + b_n = \frac {(a_{n - 1} + b_{n - 1})^2 + 5} {a_{n - 1}} = a_{n - 1} + 2 b_{n - 1} + \frac {b_{n - 1}^2 + 5} {a_{n - 1}}.$$ Hence, $$b_n = b_{n - 1} + \frac {b_{n - 1}^2 + 5} {a_{n - 1}}.$$

Comment: @ColmBhandal It doesn't. It's just a hint. I used this to arrive at the result, so it's natural to expect that OP may also arrive at it as well. Thank you for your concern.

Comment: OK. I have deleted my overly harsh comment. Still, the convention for hints on this website is to start an answer with the word "Hint:" in bold, either as a heading, or using bold font e.g. **Hint:**.

Answer (score 2):

$7=3S+2T\\
18=7S+3T$

is a linear system of two equations with two unknowns.
It has a unique solution :
by multiplying the first line by $3$ and the second by $2$, then substracting, you get $21-36 = 9S-14S$, so $-15 = -5S$, then $S=3$, and then $T=-1$.

Let $b_n$ be the sequence defined by $b_0=a_0, b_1=a_1, b_{n+2}=Sb_{n+1}+Tb_n$.
You want to show that the recurrence relation defining $a_n$ is also valid for $b_n$, i.e. $b_nb_{n+2} - b_{n+1}^2 - 5 = 0$

Since $(b_n)$ satisfies a linear recurrent equation of order $2$, $(b_n^2)$ and $(b_nb_{n+2})$ satisfy a recurrent linear equation of order $3$ (if I'm not mistaken, $c_{n+3} = 8c_{n+2}-8c_{n+1}+c_n$)

The constant sequence $5$ also satisfies this recurrence relation, so the whole $(b_nb_{n+2} - b_{n+1}^2 - 5)$ is a linear recurrent sequence of order $3$ (it would be of order $4$ if it wasn't the case).

To show that it is the $0$ constant you only need to show that its first three terms are $0$. Since $a_0=b_0$ and $a_1=b_1$ by definition and $S$ and $T$ were chosen so that $a_2=b_2$ and $a_3=b_3$, then you only need to check that $a_4=b_4$.

since $a_4 = 47 = 3*18-7 = b_4$, this is true, and so $a_n = b_n$ forall $n$.

Answer (score 0):

From the recurrence relation we have
$$
a_{n+1} a_{n-1} - a_n^2 = 5
=
a_{n+2} a_{n} - a_{n+1}^2.
$$
So
$$
a_{n+1} \, (a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}) = a_n \, (a_n + a_{n+2}).
$$
or
$$
\frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{a_n + a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}},
$$
This means
$$
c_n \equiv \frac{a_{n-1} + a_{n+1}}{a_n}.
$$
satisfies $c_n = c_{n+1}$, and thus is a constant.
Let $c_n = S$.
By $a_0 = 2$, $a_1 = 3$, $a_2 = (a_1^2 +5)/a_0 = 7$, we determine $S = 3$.
Thus,
$$
a_{n+1} = 3 \, a_n - a_{n-1} = S \, a_n + T \, a_{n-1},
$$
where $S = 3$, $T = -1$.